# Integration of Payum Module to my existing Zend 2 Project

Tags: paypal, zend-framework2, payum

I have already running a project in Zend Framework 2 Now i trying to integrate the Payum Module(paypal) with my existing project I have followed the instructions from

```
https://github.com/Payum/PayumModule/blob/master/docs/get-it-started.md
```

and install and configure the module. it is showing on the **ZendDeveloperTools** that the module is there now i need to move further on this but not found a way.

Is there any other documentation available that will provide step by step integration?

Answer (score 0):

The repo of the mentioned module has documentation on how to use it:
https://github.com/Payum/PayumModule/blob/master/docs/get-it-started.md